# Mapnik module not found

Tags: mapnik

After upgrading my OS to Yosemite I also wanted to go with the newest version of Mapnik. I made a clean install of OS on a new hard drive and installed all the things I need using Homebrew.

After installing successfully, when I try to import mapnik I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mapnik

Mapnik-config -v
3.0.0
```

I have tried everything I can think of and tried searching everywhere but I just can't get it running. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I uninstalled the brewed 3.0.0 version and tried installing the 2.2.0 package available at mapnik downloads site. I got that version working when I'm using
    /usr/bin/python
but not using homebrewed python. Using homebrewed python results in an error:
    >>> import mapnik
    Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
    Abort trap: 6
I guess the error comes from conflicting python versions.

Comment: Anyone? 3.0.0 version still not working. 
I can't find the Python bindings after 3.0.0 is installed using homebrew, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer. Python bindings have to be installed separately like:

```
python setup.py install
```

https://github.com/mapnik/python-mapnik